# stop localhost from running

Tags: apache-2.2

how do i stop a localhost port? i've this fortify software which is suppose to run on a similar port as a archive folder which i can't find the root of it. Is there anyway to terminate that archive so to prevent any clash?

Answer (score 1):

"localhost" means, in networking, "this computer". I don't think you wanted to know how to stop your computer ;)

Are you trying to stop the Apache service?

On Windows, this would be done (as Administrator) thus: `net stop apache` or `net stop apache2` (depending on your version of Apache).

On Linux, the command is (again, run as root): `/etc/init.d/apache stop` or `/etc/init.d/apache2 stop`

Comment: i found the archive folder in my apache folder..so how do i stop it from running in that port or redirect it to another avaliable port?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
sudo netstat -pn
```

to see what ports are open, and which PID is using the port. if the program name is not shown, you can do a `ps aux` to see what program is using the port.

To get the program to stop using the port:

- If you are allowed, kill the program - the port will be free.
- If you know the program, configure it to use another port. In Apache, this is in the `listen.conf` file.

You'll probably need to be root to do this, or use the sudo as I described.

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure what you mean by some fortify software. ok if it the apache using a port is the casue of the issue and you want to change the port to something other port , then it is a simple. Is it windows or *nix ? All apache httpd have httpd.conf or apache.conf master file and it is a plain text file. Load the file in your favourite text editor and notice if there is a `include` statement in the conf file. It is there then you have do the below steps on all the included conf file. Which is why i never use inlcudes other conf file in my apache httpd setup. Instead i make one big conf file with including nothing other conf file. And i do all customization in that file to my hearts content. And if i need mutliple server instances then i create one conf file for each instance. And i also use virtual host in the same conf file. It makes my life easier.

1. After opening master conf file look for a line starting with keyword Listen. The next to it you will find the port number where it is listening.
2. Look for any virtualhost entries in the conf file and change the port n8umber there also , make sure you understand why and what you are doing.
3. open conf file stated in the master conf file include lien and do the step 1 & 2 and repaet for each of the conf file included in the include statement in master conf file.

Hope that helps.